# Using _blank causes page to open in current and new tab

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a conditional target based on if the link is external or internal. I want the external links to open in a new tab, but the internal links to open in the current tab.

this is what I have in my template:

```
<a ng-href="{{newLink[1]}}" target="{{getLinkTarget(newLink[1])}}">{{newLink[0]}}</a>
```

newLink is an array that contains the href (1) and the name (0) to be used.

My function looks like this:

```
$scope.getLinkTarget = function(link){ if(link.indexOf('http') !== -1){ return '_blank';} return '_self';};
```

What am I doing wrong? After inspecting the element the link shows up like the correct target, but the _blank targets open in both tabs.

Thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try `ng-attr-target` instead of `target` to be sure the target attribute is only computed once angular has processed it.

However both seem to work when I try to reproduce. Which version of angular are you using?

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/9930/

Comment: Changing to `ng-attr-target` didn't work. I don't know what is going on, it loads a new tab, but it also loads in the current tab which is confusing.

Comment: Apparently my click event that was also attached to it was what was causing the problem. Thanks for the help though.